# Programmatically "rotating" focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a layout, and I want to programmatically switch focus between views. I happen to be implementing the thing that rotates focus as a view group. My layout has 3 elements: a text view and 2 buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AccessContainer2 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AccessActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_hello_world"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:nextFocusForward="@id/button_option_1"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <requestFocus/>
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_option_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Option 1"
            android:nextFocusForward="@id/button_option_2"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_option_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Option 2"
            android:nextFocusForward="@id/text_hello_world"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</AccessContainer2>
```

I've tried to define the "forward" focus for each of the 3 focusable elements as the text view, button 1, button 2 and back to the text view.

My code, in my view group impl looks like:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final View currentFocus = getFocusedChild();
    if (currentFocus == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "No current focus!");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("Currently focused child view ID: %s", getId(currentFocus)));
        View newFocus = focusSearch(currentFocus, FOCUS_FORWARD);
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("New child to focus view ID: %s", getId(newFocus)));
        if (!newFocus.requestFocus()) {
            Log.w(TAG, String.format("Failed to focus new child view ID: %s", getId(newFocus)));
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So,

1. Find the current focus.
2. Find the next "forward" focus from that.
3. Set that to the current focus.

However, I get this result:

```
04-08 14:51:33.600 14232 14232 I AccessContainer2: Currently focused child view ID: com.clover.accesswork:id/text_hello_world
04-08 14:51:33.600 14232 14232 I AccessContainer2: New child to focus view ID: com.clover.accesswork:id/button_option_1
04-08 14:51:34.721 14232 14232 I AccessContainer2: Currently focused child view ID: com.clover.accesswork:id/buttons
04-08 14:51:34.724 14232 14232 I AccessContainer2: New child to focus view ID: com.clover.accesswork:id/text_hello_world
```

So on the first touch, it finds button_option_1 as the next focus, but when I call request focus on it, it sets that view's container (buttons) to have focus... even though I explicitly told it that layout is not focusable and that it should prefer to focus its descendants (although I don't think that should be required on a linear layout, but just trying things).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was an "RTFM" bug. It turns out that `getFocusedChild()` is documented as:

> Returns the focused child of this view, if any. **The child may have
>   focus or contain focus.**

So in this case, it was returning the view that contained focus, not the child with focus. I wrote this function to get the child view that actually has focus:

```
private View getFocused(ViewGroup vg) {
    View focused = vg.getFocusedChild();
    if (focused == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (focused instanceof ViewGroup) {
        // Figure out if a child of the view group has focus
        // Recursion!
        View v = getFocused((ViewGroup) focused);
        if (v == null) {
            // The view group itself actually has focus
            return focused;
        } else {
            // A child of the view group had focus
            return v;
        }
    }
    // A non-view group child had focus
    return focused;
}
```